# Doesn't this cipher suite mention key size - "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"?

Tags: rsa, java-8, public-key-encryption

I had assumed that the RSA key size would be 256. But it can't.

On trying to generate RSA keystore using keytool it gives error "rsa keys must be at least 512 bits long".

The command used is - "keytool -genkey -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore RSAkeystore.jks -keysize 256".

Answer (score 1):

This cipher suite defines the key size for the AES algorithm but not for the RSA algorithm. The details about the cipher suite string you provided can be understood by reading [RFC 4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492)

Comment: What would be the keyalg for RSA_WITH_AES?

Comment: @user3009968: That's like asking who's buried in Grant's tomb.